# Why tinyproxy requires an upstream proxy?

Tags: proxy

Today I configured a basic tinyproxy.
I expected it to act as proxy for ubuntu repositories.
But when trying to download stuff from repositories I got this on tinyproxy log

```
CONNECT   Mar 27 17:30:46 [20348]: Connect (file descriptor 9): [unknown] [192.168.2.30]
CONNECT   Mar 27 17:30:46 [20348]: Request (file descriptor 9): GET http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/tdb/python-tdb_1.2.12-1_amd64.deb HTTP/1.1
INFO      Mar 27 17:30:46 [20348]: No upstream proxy for br.archive.ubuntu.com
ERROR     Mar 27 17:30:56 [20348]: opensock: Could not retrieve info for br.archive.ubuntu.com
INFO      Mar 27 17:30:56 [20348]: no entity
```

I stuck on some misconcept. Do not tinyproxy send requests for outside servers directly?
I supllied an external proxy server to fix this

```
upstream 117.79.64.29:80
```

Comment: Are you sure the `INFO` line in your log extract is an error? It could only mean that no proxy chain was configured for that domain, without implying that tinyproxy has to enforce a proxy chain.
Did you see what tinyproxy is doing with a traffic capture (without the `upstream` config)?

Comment: I will try give a look at that. The host where tinyproxy is configured has Internet access. Expected it to translate requests forward to destination. But without upstream got no connection outside. See the error message below the INFO on log. By some reason it could not connect directly.

Comment: I had the same problem. Fixing DNS (/etc/resolv.conf) was the solution. Try curl or wget on the host running tinyproxy and you will probably see the same error message ("Could not retrieve")

Comment: Yes, you are right, that problem was a momentary failure on access to BOTH configured DNS servers. That tricked about the upstream message.

Comment: @DanielAlder You mentioned "Fixing DNS (/etc/resolv.conf) was the solution." How do I fix the DNS?

Comment: @sbhhbs The DNS setup was just broken. I tried wget with the same URL on the tinyproxy host and got "Could not retrieve" because the hostname didn't resolve on that system. I had to fix the DNS resolver setup (define an existing DNS server) to make it working again.